# Avoid unwanted scrolling triggered by keyboard navigation in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an HTML page in which there is a <div> that contains content that is wider than itself; the excess is made invisible with the style "overflow: hidden;".

There can be links in this content.  In IE8 (but not Firefox 3.6), if you use the keyboard (i.e., tab key) to set focus to a link that is clipped at the right edge, IE will scroll the entire div left far enough to make the whole link visible.  (The same thing happens with links on the left when they get focus, if the div has already been scrolled left -- it scrolls the contents right to make the entire link visible.)

I can attempt to hide this undesired scrolling by setting the scrollLeft value on the div when it gets out of whack -- jQuery makes this easy.  But I would prefer, if possible, to use a style or setting to prevent the scrolling in the first place.  As mentioned, Firefox doesn't scroll a partially clipped link into view when it gets focus.  Ideally, IE should be made to behave the same way.

Sample HTML below.  In IE, use Tab (or Shift+Tab) to set focus to each link in turn to see the contents of the box shift sideways.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Demo of undesired scrolling</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.w3.org">Before</a>
    <div style="width: 400px; border: 1px solid gray; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <div style="width: 450px; text-align: center;">
                <a href="http://www.w3.org">Somewhere in the middle</a>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 450px; text-align: left;">
                <a href="http://www.w3.org">Over on the left</a>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 450px; text-align: right;">
                <a href="http://www.w3.org">Over on the right</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.w3.org">After</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: This is very similar to [a question I just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13827409/925897).

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's any "natural" way to prevent the scrolling, but you do have a few options using JS:

Option #1

- Check to see if the link is out of view in the onfocus event.
- If it is out of view, either just blur it, or preferably find the next valid link and focus that.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/eHTVV/2/
- If your links are partially visible, this will act weird since they will be un-selectable.

---

Option #2

- reset the scroll position in the onscroll event of the container div in all situations other than scrolling with jQuery.
- You will need to store a variable that has the correct scroll position in the jquery animation events, e.g.:

  ```
  var correctXOffset = 0;
  myDiv.animate({ left: 500 }, function(){
      correctXOffset = this.offsetLeft;
  });
  ```
- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eHTVV/3/
- All links outside of the view will still be selectable, but you won't be able to see them, but I suppose this is how the other browsers probably act anyway.

---

Option #3

- Remove the invisible links from the tab-index order whenever your div is done scrolling, e.g.:

  ```
  myDiv.animate({ left : 500 }, function(){
      $('.invisiblePage a').prop('tabIndex', -1);
      $('.visiblePage a'  ).removeProp('tabIndex');
  });
  ```
- Like option #1, links will become un-selectable

---

Option #4

- "Clip" the content using CSS: `clip : rect(0px 400px 400px 0px);`
- The container ***must*** be positioned absolutely
- somewhat complicated JS has to adjust this property
- demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/eHTVV/5/

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just fit everything inside the containing div?

I fixed scrolling problem that way... substitute this:

```
        <div style="width: 400px; text-align: right;">
```

for line 16 in your example.

does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, your suggestion would fix this example, but this is just a sample to illustrate the problem I'm seeing (and to prove to myself that it's really a problem with the browser, not with my page). The real page in question has two full pages of content side by side, with jQuery animations to do a smooth transition from one to the other, and some links which are partially revealed at the edge and which animate into full view on hover or focus. Works nicely in Firefox... but IE unhelpfully scrolls as described above.  Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: I tried using what I know of css and couldn't... however I am probably not as experienced as you are... I only know HTML and CSS... so maybe someone else can help. I would be interested to see what could be done.

Comment: I tried floats just a minute ago and earlier I experimented with positioning, z-index, and reworking the divs... nothing seems to work...

Comment: My brother (who is my main teacher, and a full time web developer) said he has not seen this before, and that it definitely looks like a bug...