# Prevent scrolling while keyboard tabbing

Tags: javascript, keyboard, scroll, tabbing

See the following test: http://jsfiddle.net/JgwWM/embedded/result/

Try to tab with your tab key to each one of the 3 anchor links in Firefox and in Chrome or Safari.

Do you notice that in Firefox, there is no scrolling while in Chrome or Safari, there is?
How can I prevent scrolling in Chrome and Safari too?

You don't have to indicate the usability concerns since this is just a dry test and I am applying it with usability and accessibility in mind.

**EDIT**

Similar question: [Avoid unwanted scrolling triggered by keyboard navigation in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653331/avoid-unwanted-scrolling-triggered-by-keyboard-navigation-in-ie)

Comment: Don't (even try to) alter browser behaviour.

Comment: Since you can't see all links at once, why *shouldn't* it scroll?

Comment: @You What are we all doing with JavaScript then? Oftentimes, isn't JavaScript changing the browsers default behavior Event.preventDefault(), scrollTo(), ... ?

Comment: @deceze Because overflow will be set to hidden and I will move the links with a CSS property like margin via JavaScript. Think of a viewport with inside of it a container that moves.

Comment: @DADU: I'd rather they didn't. I like the way my browser works, and I don't want some smug web developer changing it because they think some other way works better. **If I tab my way to a link, I want to see where it is.** And I think most people do.

Comment: @You Off course you do. So do I. "You don't have to indicate the usability concerns since this is just a dry test and I am applying it with usability and accessibility in mind." There is a reason why I've put that into the question. I knew someone would start questioning my question. So I would appreciate it if you could contribute a solution without prejudices about the developer.

Comment: @DADU: Just explaining why I recommend that you don't alter browser behaviour. Most people who do aren't considerate enough to take care of usability, and most people who will read this question (and its answers) won't care, unfortunately. I'm glad that you do.

Comment: @You're right, didn't think of it this way. It's true that a lot of folks underestimate the importance of usability. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If I am understanding the Q correctly, just change

```
.scrollblock {
height:200px;
overflow:scroll;   
}
```

to

```
.scrollblock {
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but it's not about the scrollbars, it's the scrolling itself while tabbing that I want to prevent.