# How to prevent a <div> floating on top of other divs in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, css

In the project that I'm doing, I have multiple divisions one below another and I load them one after other depending on the navbar choice. Now that works fine if I don't have any fancy elements in the `<div>`. But when I added a form to a div it started floating on the div above it. This happens when I select any element in form. Also, I can't seem to be able to select any item that's there in the `dropDown` list that's there in the `<form>`.

Here is sample code of the list of divisions

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="st-container">

                    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
                    <a href="#st-panel-1">Serendipity</a>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"/>
                    <a href="#st-panel-2">Happiness</a>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3"/>
                    <a href="#st-panel-3">Tranquillity</a>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4"/>
                    <a href="#st-panel-4">Positivity</a>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-5"/>
                    <a href="#st-panel-5">Passion</a>

                    <div class="st-scroll">


                            <div class="st-panel" id="st-panel-1">
                                <h2>Serendipity</h2>
                                <p>Banksy adipisicing eiusmod banh mi sed. Squid stumptown est odd future nisi, commodo mlkshk pop-up adipisicing retro.</p>
                            </div >

                   <!--problematic div starts-->         
               <div id="RepresentativeRegistrationPage" class="st-panel st-color">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="registration-form" novalidate="novalidate">
            College:
            <select class="required" id="college_id" name="college_id">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Select College</option>
            <option value="4">St. Xaviers College</option>
            <option value="5">DMC College</option>
            </select><span class="error_msg"></span><br>

            First Name: <input type="text" value="" class="required" name="first_name" id="first_name"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" value="" class="required" name="last_name" id="last_name"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            Username: <input type="text" class="required" name="username" id="username"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            Password: <input type="password" class="required" name="password" id="password"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            Confirm Password: <input type="password" class="required" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            Mobile Number: <input type="text" value="" class="required" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            Email address: <input type="text" value="" class="required" name="email" id="email"><span class="error_msg"></span><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
        </form>
        </div>
                            <!--problematic div ends -->  

             <div class="st-panel" id="st-panel-3">
                      <h2>Tranquillity</h2>
                      <p>Sint aute occaecat id vice. Post-ironic fap pork belly next level godard, id fanny pack williamsburg forage truffaut.</p>
             </div>

             <div class="st-panel st-color" id="st-panel-4">
                       <h2>Positivity</h2>
                       <p>Mixtape fap leggings art party, butcher authentic farm-to-table you probably haven't heard of them do labore cosby sweater.</p>
             </div>

             <div class="st-panel" id="st-panel-5">
                        <h2>Passion</h2>
                        <p>Fixie ad odd future polaroid dreamcatcher, nesciunt carles bicycle rights accusamus mcsweeney's mumblecore nulla irony.</p>
             </div>

      </div><!-- // st-scroll -->

    </div><!-- // st-container -->
```

And here is the CSS

```
.st-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.st-container > input,
.st-container > a {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.st-container > input {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.st-container > a {
    z-index: 10;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #e23a6e;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(151,24,64,0.2);
}

/* "Fix" for percentage rounding: add a background bar pseudo element with the same color like the labels */
.st-container:before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    background: #e23a6e;
    z-index: 9;
    bottom: 0;
}

#st-control-1, #st-control-1 + a {
    left: 0;
}

#st-control-2, #st-control-2 + a {
    left: 20%;
}

#st-control-3, #st-control-3 + a {
    left: 40%;
}

#st-control-4, #st-control-4 + a {
    left: 60%;
}

#st-control-5, #st-control-5 + a {
    left: 80%;
}

.st-container > input:checked + a,
.st-container > input:checked:hover + a{
    background: #821134;
}

.st-container > input:checked + a:after,
.st-container > input:checked:hover + a:after{
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #821134;
    border-width: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.st-container > input:hover + a{
    background: #AD244F;
}

.st-container > input:hover + a:after {
    border-bottom-color: #AD244F;
}

.st-scroll,
.st-panel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.st-scroll {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;

    /* Let's enforce some hardware acceleration */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.st-panel{
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#st-control-1:checked ~ .st-scroll {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    -o-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
#st-control-2:checked ~ .st-scroll {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
#st-control-3:checked ~ .st-scroll {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-200%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-200%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-200%);
    transform: translateY(-200%);
}
#st-control-4:checked ~ .st-scroll {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-300%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-300%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-300%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-300%);
    transform: translateY(-300%);
}
#st-control-5:checked ~ .st-scroll {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-400%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-400%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-400%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-400%);
    transform: translateY(-400%);
}


/* Content elements */

.st-deco{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background: #fa96b5;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

[data-icon]:after {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: 'RaphaelIcons';
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(151,24,64,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
}

.st-panel h2 {
    color: #e23a6e;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(151,24,64,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 54px;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: -70px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#st-control-1:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-1 h2,
#st-control-2:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-2 h2,
#st-control-3:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-3 h2,
#st-control-4:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-4 h2,
#st-control-5:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-5 h2{
    -webkit-animation: moveDown 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    -moz-animation: moveDown 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    -o-animation: moveDown 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    -ms-animation: moveDown 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    animation: moveDown 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveDown{
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes moveDown{
    0% {
        -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveDown{
    0% {
        -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes moveDown{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.st-panel p {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#st-control-1:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-1 p,
#st-control-2:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-2 p,
#st-control-3:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-3 p,
#st-control-4:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-4 p,
#st-control-5:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-5 p{
    -webkit-animation: moveUp 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    -moz-animation: moveUp 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    -o-animation: moveUp 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    -ms-animation: moveUp 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
    animation: moveUp 0.6s ease-in-out 0.2s backwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveUp{
    0% {
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes moveUp{
    0% {
        transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Colored sections */

.st-color,
.st-deco{
    background: #fa96b5;
}
.st-color [data-icon]:after {
    color: #fa96b5;
}
.st-color .st-deco {
    background: #fff;
}
.st-color h2 {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.st-color p {
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .st-panel h2 {
        font-size: 42px;
    }

    .st-panel p {
        width: 90%;
        left: 5%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .st-container > a {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .st-container > a {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .st-deco{
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        margin-left: -60px;
    }


}
body{
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    background: #ddd;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a{
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.clr{
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
```

This problem only happens in Firefox ( I'm using Firefox 16.0). 
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGFat/4/) of the problem. Click on the "Happiness" option in navbar to get to the problematic section.
Can someone please help me sort out the issue?

Comment: if possible add a screenshot.

Comment: ok, I'll put up a screenshot. but till then You can take a look at the example itself at http://jsfiddle.net/DGFat/4/

Comment: I tested it using Chrome and I am able to select the items from Dropdown. You have .clr class but I can't see you have used it anywhere in your code. The .clr will 'clear' divs.

Comment: @YogeshNath yes, it works in chrome, this problem is only in FireFox.

Comment: @vineetrok in your css you have a class called .clr. After each div you need to <div class = "clr"></div>. This is what I meant by you have a .clr class but you havn't used it in your code.

Comment: @YogeshNath Yes, I have tried that, it still doesnt seem to work, here is what I did http://jsfiddle.net/DGFat/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the css magic confuses Firefox in terms of "tabbing". This is a very interesting issue because it seems like Firefox tries to locate the  tag and automatically align the viewport to make  at the top, though it already is... CSS wise, I can do nothing to help, as even with `overflow:hidden`, you can still use the middle mouse button to scroll the body and thus cause the out-of-alignment issue present in Firefox. With google chrome, pressing tab on the "Serendipity" tab multiple times will cause the viewport to scroll to the input tab directly. See [Avoid unwanted scrolling triggered by keyboard navigation in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653331/avoid-unwanted-scrolling-triggered-by-keyboard-navigation-in-ie)

However, with javascript, this can all be easily avoided, if you're willing to sacrifice the "no javascript" aspect of your site.

```
var tabs = document.getElementById("registration-form").elements;
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].setAttribute("tabindex", i + 1);
    tabs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        var e = window.event || e;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var x = window.scrollX,
                y = window.scrollY;

            var elementToFocus = document.getElementById("registration-form").elements[this.getAttribute("tabindex")];
            if (typeof elementToFocus == "undefined") {
                elementToFocus = document.getElementById("registration-form").elements[0];
            }
            elementToFocus.focus();
            window.scrollTo(x, y);

        }
    });
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    var e = window.event || e;
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DGFat/15/

Comment: I found this closest to the solution. Yes, i have to sacrifice my "CSS only" approach. But if i do it that way then my design doesnt hold up well. Thus I thought using javascript is the only solution to handle that issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to start a new div, then use clear attribute to prevent inheritance from the previous div. Something like this:

```
<div your style here></div>
<div Style="clear:both"></div>
<div You second div></div>
```

Comment: and where is the `<div Style="clear:both">` supposed to close?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that , but it doesnt seem to work, can you please help me out by doing the change in this jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/DGFat/4/

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get exactly what is your problem?! I tried to run the code in my pc, what I found that, the input element is not showing properly, if that is your problem, then I have found you didn't apply any style in your input element, try to include the input element in a span & use style to position those spans.

Comment: No, open the JSFiddle in FireFox. click in any input element, and press Tab key to go to the next element. the entire division will shift topwards as u press tab. thats the problem.

Comment: OK, got it now, let me check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18356/discussion-between-vineetrok-and-badhon-jain)

Comment: It is better to use a so called 'clearfix' class: 
    `.clearfix:before, .container:after { content: ""; display: table; } .clearfix:after { clear: both; } .clearfix { zoom: 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to put that form on center? Check this out:

Add this to your css (jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DGFat/8/)

```
form {
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width:300px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
    background: gray; /*just so you could see it better */
}
```

Comment: i had tried that too! but no matter where you position it. the problem persists. it moves up when Tab is pressed to go to the next item. plus. cant select any item from dropdown list

Comment: I have tested it with FF 16x and it worked well; see the screenshot: http://oi47.tinypic.com/2l1g05.jpg Am I missing something?

Comment: @sahil0vicX click into the First Name textBox and press tab, and let me know what happens

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your use of input for "everything".

Adding: `[type="checkbox"]` to your CSS at this declaration:
`.st-container > input, .st-container > a { ... }` becoming
`.st-container > input[type="checkbox"], .st-container > a { ... }`

Stops the tabbing issue in FF, but it breaks the positioning a little, and throws off the navigation. Sounds worse than it is.

All browsers have built-in properties for `input` elements. I think your CSS implementation just doesn't do a good enough job at isolating your functionality from presentation.